# how to start a session by adding a link and end the session in the same way and showing session datas

Tags: php, session

I have to add a link in my search screen to start a session by the user and and another link to stop the session in the result page. The result page will also will have a link to show all the wine names. I know only the basic session(). I am not getting what I have to do or code should i follow. Please suggest me something, if possible example codes.

Comment: Why do you need this ? It appears you are doing something quite wrong, even before starting to program :)

Comment: `session_start()` and `session_destroy()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can end the session with a link, by passing a $_GET parameter

```
 <a href="?logout"> Log out </a>

 <?php

  if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {

              session_destroy();
  }

 ?>
```

It is worthy to note, that you must have already started the session with `session_start()` before destroying it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <a href="?create"> Create Session </a>
<a href="?show"> Show Sessions </a>
<?php
//must have session start before destroying or starting sessions
session_start();   
if(isset($_GET['create']))
{
    //setting sessions with time, this can be equal to anything string
    $_SESSION[] = time(); 
} 
else if(isset($_GET['show'])) 
{
    //this display all sessions currently stored    
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . '</pre>';  
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the session if you want to destroy. So use this it should work

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['start'])){
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['key']=true;
 }elseif(isset($_GET['stop'])){
    session_start(); // this is need to destroy also
   session_destroy();
}
$ses_id = session_id();
if(empty($ses_id)){ ?>    
    <a href="?start">Start Session</a>  
<?php }else{ ?>
    <a href="?stop">Stop Session</a>
<?php }?>
```